# django model import error on aws ec2, but runs fine on localhost, heroku and bluemix

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2

getting the following error when accessing app on ec2 :-

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name <model_name>
..
..
Exception Location: /opt/ubuntu/projects/<project_name>/<app_name>/models.py in <module>, line 13
```

--didn't get any errors while deploying it to ec2.

--the app works fine on localhost as well as on heroku and bluemix.

Also, tried importing the model in the remote instance's python shell but got no errors :-

```
ssh -i ~/.ec2/<mykey>.pem ubuntu@54.169.xx.xxx
cd opt/ubuntu/projects/<project_name>
source ../../envs/<project_name>/bin/activate
python manage.py shell
from <app_name>.models import <model_name>
```

this unfortunately didn't give any errors.

What is causing this then?

Comment: How are you trying to serve the app? Through wsgi with gunicorn or apache? Make sure that your server is trying to run your app through the virtualenv.

Comment: How are you running your app? Do you use any scripts? From which location?